# i am not sure why you need to add the plus sign and apostrophes inside the bracket when it is inside the string function in python

Tags: python-3.x, range, operators

```
 print('My name is')
 for i in range(5):
     print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')
```

i am a beginner who just started and not sure why for this code, I am not sure why we need to put the apostrophes for the string function and why to add the plus sign inside the brackets for it to work

Comment: That's string concatenation. It's adding a string (`str(i)`) between the strings on either side. `str()` converts the integer `i` to a string.

Answer (score 1):

In this line `print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')` you're concatenating  three strings together.

1st string is `'Jimmy Five Times ('`.
2nd string is `str(i)`.
3rd string is `')'`.

Alternatively you can use the f-string to avoid the concatenation.

```
for i in range(5):
  print(f'Jimmy Five Times ({i})')
```

Comment: In this case it would be great if you could accept and upvote my answer :) thank you :)